# Passing output of a TestStep to another TestStep

Tags: opentap-proj

In the `Keysight OpenTap`

There is Test- Step 1. I would like the pass the result obtained by Test-Step 1 to any of the Test-Step-n
Example : Test-Step1 executes SCPI Query and then the result obtained from this, has to be passed to Test-Step-N.

For this approach, we have extended a Test-Step and created our own Test Step.
Is there any in-built feature In TAP we could make use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for this feature to be provided by the built-in 'Basic/Flow Steps'?

Input/Output parameters are fully supported by the OpenTAP engine and as you point out, you have created your own TestStep which I assume has utilised this approach.

Any generic Teststep that would consume the output of another TestStep would need to understand the data to make any use of it other than in the simplest of cases.

Do you have a specific example?

Comment: Thanks Jase. I understand like We can use Input/Output attribute for this.